# New Activity Fails in Async

Tags: android, android-activity, asynchronous, android-asynctask, asyncpostbackerror

**My Application is crashing when I try to start new Activity. Need Help!**

```
LoginAysnc logins = new LoginAysnc((Context) con);
logins.execute(); 



class LoginAysnc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    public LoginAysnc(Context context){
        contexts = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
            startActivity(new Intent(contexts.getApplicationContext(),home.class));

    }
```

Comment: What you doing in AsyncTask? Are calling any Api?? Can you post your doInBackground() method as well.

Comment: am trying get employee details from website in background as JsonString

Comment: 02-16 10:04:36.449 86-86/? W/InputManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 572 uid 10040
02-16 10:04:45.418 86-100/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41187748 com.goodscab.android.goodscabserviceprovider/.MainActivity}
02-16 10:04:45.418 86-100/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4128cf48 com.goodscab.android.goodscabserviceprovider/.home}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should call the method

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground() {
    // Your code to execute here
    return s;  // This is the String you get as a parameter in onPostExecute
}
```

That is the whole point of the AsyncTasks. Then your code in onPostExecute will get called. But I agree that you should post your LogCat to see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the `Context` instead of the Application Context.

```
startActivity(new Intent(contexts,home.class));
```

And check if you declared `home` `activity` in the `Manifest`.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".home"
            android:label="@string/home_page">
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

start your activity like:

startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class));